# how to mass update to custom fields (which is in custom object)description

Tags: force.com, custom-field, custom, bulk

Wondering how to update custom fields description(which is in custom objects) as a bulk update.   They are around 500 in a Excel file. Is there any mass update we can do instead of doing it manually.

Any other solution is highly appreciated.

my personal note: 
I am thinking of writing some sort of loop program, where we read the excel file and update it but not really got how to do it  in salesforce. i can do it well in java and some db like oracle or some other database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that XML modification. As you know each object in SF is XML schema.
You can download that XML object schema using Force.com IDE. Then you can write a Java program to update the description of those. You can save them,and it will reflected back in SFDC>